# How to distinguish whether onDestoy is being invoked cause appl closing or activity changing

Tags: android

I have a trackingService `locationManager`  component which processes in the background and it is launched from the `MainActivity` activity. At the same time, I have another component to retrieve this data from the server and displaying it in the `Map` activity. The user can access this data in the server from the MainActivity, when he clicks a buton in it. Thereupon, the data is being retrieved from the server and the user redirects to the `Map` activity. Everything it works for me so far.

I am trying to remove the `locationManager` in two cases:

- When the user click the checkbox in the menu of  MainActivity.
- or when he closes the app (Not when the user changes the activity).

With this code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(lm != null){
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        System.out.println("ABC lm locationManager is not equal null.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("ABC lm locationManager is null.");

    }       
}
```

I have tried it with the code below so when I click the button in the MainActivity for the first time, the user is being redirected to the `Map` activity and the service works (without calling the `onDestroy()` in the `TrackingService` class) but when I go back from the Map activity to the MainActivity(Service still works) and then clicks the button to go again to the `Map` activity, at this point, the `onDestroy()` in the `TrackingService` class is being called and the service stops

How can I distinguish whether onDestoy is being invoked cause the user cloeses the app or when it being called when the user Switches between the activities?

I appreciate any help.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AsyncTaskCallback {
    TrackingService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.route_available);
        // Start the TrackingService class.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        startService(i);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        System.out.println("test onCreateOptionsMenu was invoked.");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem checkable = menu.findItem(R.id.checkable_menu);
        checkable.setChecked(isChecked);
        return true;
    }

    // Start and stop the background service.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.checkable_menu:
            if (isChecked = !item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(isChecked);
                Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
                startService(i);
                System.out.println("test if onOptionsItemSelected");
            } else {
                mService.stopTrackingService();

            }
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
    stopService(i);

}

}
```

**TrackingService class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
    LocationManager lm;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        detectLocation();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private void detectLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside detectlocation()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,
                this);
        enableGPS(lm);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        System.out.println("ABC locationManager is not equal null.");       
    }

    public void stopTrackingService(){
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
```

**Map activity:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
 // To stop the service when the user closed the app in the background and the map ativity was opened.      
        stopAlarm();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        stopService(i);
        System.out.println("ABC Map onDestroy() was invoked!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the `Activity.isFinishing()` method? I think it can help you.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev: Also isFinishing is being called in both cases when the user Closes the app or the user changes the activity. I have teasted it.